# Where to create user object in Flask web app

Tags: python, flask

1. I am trying to build a Flask web app which accepts input parameters from users, uses those parameters to fetch some data, perform some processing (taking about2-3 minutes), and show the output to user.
2. I am trying to follow Miguel's Flask Mega Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)
3. I have created the User class which will accept the user specific inputs, and will process and generate output.
4. Problem is, where should I create object for the User class (for each user opening the UI)? If I create it inside the **init**.py, it becomes global, and so one user's data overwrites another's.
5. I think it should be created in routes.py, but how to share the objects across different view functions in the routes?

I am quite new to Web Service in General and Flask in particular, so please excuse if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question then you should follow these steps:

1. create a form in your html page which will take the data from the user and set the action parameter of that form to a route where all the processing will occur like saving that data into the database.
2. Now you can easily compare the data with the existing data and can fetch anything which you want depending on what you want to fetch and on what basis.
3. Get that fetched data, save that in a variable and simply pass that to the tempelate using jinja syntax and that will be shown to the user now.

Comment: Thanks Irfan, The problem is that the user interaction takes 2-3 steps (user needs to choose data source, then I load metadata specific to the data source, then user provides additional inputs) and during this period if I have multiple users, there data is getting mixed up. However, I think the problem is about all being anonymous user (thanks for the point on database), let me incorporate user login and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Make the data user specific.That will solve your problems. Btw if i helped you in any way please leave a vote.Thanks .

Comment: Thanks Irfan, moving from anonymous user to user login solved the problem.

Comment: Please leave a vote and if it helped you, mark my answer as accepted.Thanks!